# Mapping VCF file into POJO

Tags: java, vcf-vcard

I am trying to map `.vcf` to my `DTO` (Simple POJO) , here is what i have tried :

**Code:**

```
List<VCard> list = Ezvcard.parse(fr).all(); // fr is FileReader
SomeDto someDto = new SomeDto ();
List<SomeDto > someDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Iterator<VCard> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    VCard vCard = iterator.next();
    c.setFirstName(vCard.getFormattedName().getValue());
    c.setEmailAddress(vCard.getEmails().get(0).getValue());
    c.setMobilePhone(vCard.getTelephoneNumbers().get(0).getText());
    someDtoList .add(c);
}
return someDtoList ;
```

Is there a simplified way of handling this? Like in-built methods to take care if DTO has more properties, so we can avoid manual work?

I am using vCard JAR: https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this out https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard it was originally a development by google and offers a lot of possibilities.

U may try to convert your vcards to json, to have more possibilities for further work.

```
String json = Ezvcard.writeJson(vcard).go();
```

Comment: You just linked to the same library linked by OP.

Comment: Sorry, i missed the last line. Maybe the op may use my suggestion to convert it to json. Thank you for your remark.